# Are multiple realloc more expensive than a huge malloc?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I am using a dynamic array to represent a min-heap. There is a loop that removes minimum, and add random elements to the min-heap until some condition occur. Although I don't know how the length of the heap will change during run-time (there is a lot of randomness), I know the upper bound, which is 10 million. I have two options:

**1)** Declare a small array using malloc, then call realloc when there number of elements in the heap exceeds the length.

**2)** Declare a 10 million entry array using malloc. This avoids ever calling realloc.

**Question**

Is option 2 more efficient than option 1?

I tested this with my code and there seems to be significant (20%) run-time reduction from using 2. This is estimated because of the randomness in the code. Is there any drawback to declaring a large 10-50 million entry array with malloc up front?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can spare the memory to make the large up-front allocation, and it gives a worthwhile performance increase, then by all means do it.

If you stick with `realloc`, then you might find that doubling the size every time instead of increasing by a fixed amount can give a good trade-off between performance and efficient memory usage.

Answer (score 4):

It's not said that when you use realloc, the memory will be expanded from the same place.It may also happen that the memory will be displaced in another area.
So using realloc may cause to copy the previous chuck of memory that you had.
Also consider that a system call may take some overhead, so you'd better call malloc once.

Answer (score 2):

The drawback is that if you are not using all that space you are taking up a large chunk of memory which might be needed. If you know exactly how many bytes you need it is going to be more efficient to allocate at once, due to system call overhead, then to allocate it piece by piece. Usually you might have an upper bound but not know the exact number. Taking the time to malloc up the space to handle the upper bound might take 1 second. If however, this particular case only has half of the upper bound it might take .75 seconds allocating piece by piece. So it depends on how close to the upper bound you think you are going to get.