# How to realloc another size with realloc

Tags: c, realloc

I have a program which takes as input a Name and if the input is less then the allowed size  it will be saved in a Pointer.

If the input is bigger then allowed size then the `realloc` function will be used to satisfy the memory needed.
The program at this point allocates only 6 bytes, 5 for name `MICHI` and 1 for '\0'.
If the user types `MICHAEL` then the program allocates enough memory for that pointer to fit `MICHAEL` inside that pointer.

Here is the Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person{
    char *name;
}pers;

void addMem(void){
    unsigned int length = 6;
    size_t newLength = 0;
    unsigned int newSize = 0;
    unsigned int i =0;
    char *name;
    int c;

    name = malloc(lenght);
    if(name == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    newSize = length;

    printf("Enter your name:>  ");

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c!=EOF){
        name[i++]=(char)c;

        if(i == newSize){
            newSize = i+length;
            name = realloc(name, newSize);
        }
    }

    name[i] = '\0';

    newLength = strlen(name)+1;
    pers.name = malloc(newLength);

    memcpy(pers.name, name, newLength);

    free(name);
    name = NULL;
}

int main(void){
    addMem();

    printf("Your name is:>  %s\n",pers.name);
    free(pers.name);
    pers.name = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

The Program works fine, but I need to make it somehow that realloc() will give only a maximum size of memory, because at this point it will realloc until User pres ENTER.

This means that i have **6** byte for **Michi** (**5 + 1** for **'\0'**) and the maximum size should be **8** (**7** for **Michael** and **1** for **'\0'**).

How can I do that?

**EDIT:**

I hope you understand now.

My program accept only names with **5** letters.
At some point I decided that may program should accept names with max **10** Letters.
I allocated already memory for 5 (michi).
If you type Michael we have 7 letters so the program should allocate another two for Michael.
But if i type Schwarzernegger, well this name is too long i do not accept it so i need to make my program to allocate memory only for michael.

Comment: Why do you `malloc(sizof(char*)*...)`?

Comment: It's *length* (not lenght).

Comment: @EOF I made an edit, fast typing and less thinking.

Comment: @Jens Sir, was fast typing

Comment: You are not allocating 6 bytes in the beginning. You are allocating 24 on 32bit environment and 48 on a 64bit since you're using `sizeof(char*)`

Comment: Did you read [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)? You should!

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen malloc(lenght); it's ok ? length = 6.

Comment: You are apparently aware that `malloc()` can fail. What do you think `realloc()` does when no more memory is available?

Comment: What exactly you want to do? You want the program to `realloc` every time you _press a key_?

Comment: @EOF Sir, I  tried to show a code here to show my point and there is the question too, i know that the code is not ok. The question is my problem.

Comment: @EnzoFerber, The program does what you say and not that i need. I need to alocate memory for **michael** which is 8.

Comment: What you're doing looks fine.  You're re-allocating memory in blocks of 6 bytes for your string.  There's nothing wrong with allocating a few extra bytes.  It's actually preferable to allocate memory in this way rather than reallocating one byte at a time, which is inefficient.

Comment: @EnzoFerber i hope. My program save the name Michi in that pointer, but if i type michael it will not fit because Michael have 7 + 1 for '\0' and the program at this point allocates memory until enter is pressed, but me, I need to realloc only 8.

Comment: @Michi, under no circumstance is any string "saved in a pointer".  A string may be stored in an existing block of memory to which a particular pointer points, but it is crucial to understand that such a block of memory is not the same thing as any pointer to it, and that pointer variables do not have any special association with whatever memory their values point to at any given time.

Comment: @dbush My program accept only name with 5 letters let's say **michi** and it is ok, but we know that there are longer names that 5 letter so i need to realloc , for Michael so the longest name will be accepted with 7 letters. Do you understand now ?

Comment: I made an Edit, please read it and i hope you understand now.

Comment: For Michael size of name becomes 12, but it work's fine. As dbush said allocating few extra bytes is preferable.

Comment: @Michi: There is **no point** to save a few bytes in the allocation. If your maximum allocation is 10 bytes, only using 5 of them is **much saner** than calling `realloc()` multiple times. Just `malloc(10)` from the start.

Comment: If there is a fixed upper bound on how many bytes you are willing to accept (i.e. not "Schwarzernegger"), and it is even somewhat reasonable, then it is far better to declare an array of that size than to mess around with dynamic allocation.

Comment: Why not use a static buffer and copy at the end ? here you are growing one bye one is not a good idea. You can realloc with a double size for example

Comment: Why are you downVote me if you do not understand me ? ok i will edit name to 12 and michael to 16 if you wont to, but this is not my Question at all.

Comment: I need to modify my program to stop realloc if the name is bigger that Michael 7 letters.

Comment: Why do you need it to stop after 7 letters?  It's an artificial constraint.  If you don't have a good reason to stop, then don't.  If you do want to limit it to 7 characters, then don't even bother with `malloc` or `realloc`.  Just define `name` as `char name[8];` and be done with it.

Comment: @dbush ...with the caveat that `char name[8]` cannot be returned to the caller.

Comment: @EOF Right, the definition of `struct person` would have to change to `char name[8]` internally as well.

Comment: @dbush iI have and i will explain it another time, need to go work now. I got my answer and trust me i need this approach.

Comment: @dbush Sir, why should I allocate memory at a beginning if an User type only 3 or 4 letters? The program doesn't need realloc isn't it ? But if the user type 7 letters then the Program realloc memory for those 7 letters

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Enzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1928852/enzo-ferber)'s answer to stop after 7 letter you can use.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
name[i++] = (char) c;

if (i >= length) {
    if(i+1<=7)
       name = realloc(name, i + 1);
    else
       {
          //generate error message
       }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i was intended, thank you , thank you Enzo

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down your main loop:

```
unsigned int length = 6;
unsigned int newSize = 0;

name = malloc(length);
...
newSize = length;

while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c!=EOF){
    name[i++]=(char)c;

    if(i == newSize){
        newSize = i+length;
        name = realloc(name, newSize);
    }
}
```

You start out allocating 6 bytes for `name`.  That's good for 5 characters plus a NULL byte.  Then for each character you read you add it to the end of `name`.

On each iteration, you check if the number of characters you entered is equal to the allocated size of the buffer.  If so, you `realloc` the buffer and add 6 more bytes, so now it's 12 bytes long.

You then keep going, reading more characters.  If you find that you've entered 12 characters, you `realloc` 6 more bytes, so now `name` is 18 bytes long.

This is a good approach.  By doing it this way, you're allocating enough memory to hold whatever the user types in, with up to 5 extra bytes allocated.  So there's no need to restrict the name to 7 bytes or any other specific number.  You could add a check that says if the total number of characters is more than 7 bytes, print an error and exit, but there doesn't appear to be any good reason to do so.

EDIT:

If a name will never be longer than 7 bytes, you could do this instead of `malloc` and `realloc` for `name`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person{
    char *name;
}pers;

void addMem(void){
    unsigned int i = 0;
    char name[8];
    int c;

    printf("Enter your name:>  ");

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c!=EOF){
        name[i++]=(char)c;

        if(i == sizeof(name)){
            printf("name too long\n");
            pers.name = NULL;
            return;
        }
    }

    name[i] = '\0';

    pers.name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
    strcpy(pers.name, name);
}

int main(void){
    addMem();

    printf("Your name is:>  %s\n",pers.name);
    free(pers.name);
    pers.name = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

This way, your internal buffer that reads the name is a fixed size, and when you're done reading the name you still allocate just enough space to copy the string to `pers.name`.

Comment: i need to stop realloc if user type longer name more than 7 letters.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation on how many memory you should get is wrong. 
(As @dbush said in a comment, it's fine since you're allocating memory in blocks of `6 bytes`, **which is more efficient than allocating by bytes**)

Anyway, to change your behavior of allocating in blocks of 6 bytes to allocating in bytes, do this:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    name[i++] = (char) c;

    /* added IF requests on comments */
    if (i > 7) {
        printf("Names longer than 7 not allowed!\n");
        name[7] = 0x0;
        break;
    }
    else if (i >= length) 
        name = realloc(name, newSize);
}
```

Which will print:

```
$ ./draft
Enter your name:>  Michael
reallocing 7
reallocing 8
Your name is:>  Michael

$ ./draft
Enter your name:>  StackOverflow          
reallocing 7
reallocing 8
reallocing 9
reallocing 10
reallocing 11
reallocing 12
reallocing 13
reallocing 14
Your name is:>  StackOverflow

$ ./draft
Enter your name:>  Michi
Your name is:>  Michi
```

---

### Read More

- [Malloc, Calloc and Realloc Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html)
- [Are multiple realloc more expensive than a huge malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825096/are-multiple-realloc-more-expensive-than-a-huge-malloc)

As [dbush Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32638895/1928852) says, you are better off allocating a big memory block and using realloc as few times as possible. The second link sustains that. It also suggests that you should use a **second loop** just to calculate the size you need, so you only need to call `malloc` once.

Comment: All most there, i need the realloc to stop if user type more than 7 letters.

Comment: char *name should hold only 5 letters and if user type michael should realoc for another 2 letters. But if user type a longer name  (**longer than 7 letter**s)like Schwarzernegger the program should not allocate that memory.

Comment: @Michi Put a `if` before the existent `if`. This conditional must test **if the value of the variable `i` is equal to 7, then `break` the loop.**

Comment: @michi `if(i > 7) { printf("No names longer than 7 allowed!"); break; }`

Comment: Yes, this is what i was needed. Sorry but i cannot accept to Answers. Thank you